# What is the purpose of all these semanage rules in my nextcloud installation with nginx + php-fpm in centos7?

Tags: php, nginx, centos7, selinux, nextcloud

### My scenario

I have set up 1 VM (centos7) with:

- Nginx
- php-fpm
- Nextcloud

For this task, I have followed [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-install-nextcloud-with-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-centos-7/) (of course, I had to change some settings to make it work in my environment)

### My question

In some point of the guide, I had to execute all these lines

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/nextcloud/data(/.*)?'
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/nextcloud/config(/.*)?'
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/nextcloud/apps(/.*)?'
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/nextcloud/assets(/.*)?'
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/nextcloud/.htaccess'
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/nextcloud/.user.ini'

sudo restorecon -Rv '/var/www/nextcloud'
```

The only experience I've had with selinux was to alter the value of the boolean "httpd_can_network_connect_db". I had to do this because my database is located in another vm.

Just by reading a little bit the manpage of semanage, its options...etc, I guess that this is allowing the reading and writing if they access via nextcloud to my directories in the document root? (I'm just guessing since "httpd_sys_rw_content_t" seems to me like "read and write content")

> By the way, my nextcloud installation is working properly, I'm just asking all of this because I want to understand what I did and why when I followed the installation guide

---

So what I want to learn and currently I can't understand is:

- **What are these selinux rules doing over the directories of my document root? Is what I said previously about the semanage rules right?**
- **Are they allowing the access for reading and writing files into my directories because nextcloud is like a dropbox?**
- **What is restorecon doing after aplying all the semanage rules? Only If I execute that "restorecon" line, the rules will be applied?**

Comment: you use semanage in linux because you use selinux, so in order your folder in /var/www/nextcloud/data can be access from other server using http you must to use semanage you can read more in this https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux